# Move file from inbound adapter after publish subscribe flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to implement the following flow:
1) files are read from inbound adapter
2) they are send to different flows using publish-subscribe channel with applied sequence
3) file is moved after all the subscriber flows are ready

This is the main flow

```
return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Files.inboundAdapter(inboundOutDirectory)
                           .regexFilter(pattern)
                           .useWatchService(true)
                           .watchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                                             .taskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize))
                                             .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .transform(Files.toStringTransformer())
                                .<String>handle((p, h) -> {
                                       return "something"
                                    }
                                })                                
                                .channel("consolidateFlow.input"))
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .transform(Files.toStringTransformer())
                                .handle(Http.outboundGateway(testUri)
                                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                                            .uriVariable("text", "payload")                                            .expectedResponseType(String.class))
                                .<String>handle((p, h) -> {
                                    return "something";
                                })
                                .channel("consolidateFlow.input")))
                .get();
```

And the aggregation:

```
public IntegrationFlow consolidateFlow()
return flow -> flow
                .aggregate()
                .<List<String>>handle((p, h) -> "something").log()
    }
}
```

Using the following code in the main flow after publish-subscribe

```
.handle(Files.outboundGateway(this.inboundProcessedDirectory).deleteSourceFiles(true))
```

ends up with

`Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available`

If I go with this the consolidation/aggregation flow won't be reached at all.

```
.handle(Files.outboundAdapter(this.inboundProcessedDirectory))
```

Any idea how I could solve it? Currently I'm moving the file after the aggregation by reading the original file name from the header but it doesn't seem to be the right solution.
I was also thinking about applying spec/advice to the inbound adapter with *success* logic to move the file but not sure whether that's the right approach.

***EDIT1***
As suggested by Artem, I've added another subscriber to the publish-subscribe as follows:

```
...
.channel("consolidateNlpFlow.input"))
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(this.inboundProcessedDirectory).deleteSourceFiles(true))
...
```

The files is moved properly, but the consolidateFlow is not being executed at all. Any idea?
I've also tried adding the channel to the new flow `.channel("consolidateNlpFlow.input")` but it didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem that a `consolidateFlow` is not able to return result into the main flow. Just because there is anything gateway-like. You do there an explicit `.channel("consolidateFlow.input")` which means there is not going to be way back. 
That's for the issue you have so far.

Regarding a possible solution.

According to your configuration both your subscribers in the `publishSubscribeChannel` are performed on the same thread, one by one. So, it is going to be very easy for you to add one more subscriber with that `Files.outboundAdapter()` and `deleteSourceFiles(true)`. This one is going to be called already after existing subscribers.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know that publish-subscribe is being executed sequentially. Could you please take a look at the EDIT1?

Comment: Hi @artem-bilan, any chance to look at the EDIT1?

Comment: Last try ;) would you be so kind and take a look at EDIT1?

Comment: Why do you need that aggregation at all? What is that `.channel("consolidateNlpFlow.input"))`? How does it look in the main flow? Please, consider to use a *Scatter-Gather* for your use-case if you can't live without an aggregation after distribution. You can add `Files.outboundAdapter(this.inboundProcessedDirectory)` into the `consolidateFlow`. Right, you would need to extract a file from headers, indeed, but that's should be a solution, too. Right now I'm lost in your config and i can't connect those pieces. Thanks for understanding